# How to remove part of path until a given directory is found?

Tags: php, path

I have paths that goes like this template:

```
`/dir1/dir2/dirN/dirNplus1/dirNplus2/`
```

And for an example to demonstrate this template:

```
`/var/www/sei/modules/module1/`
```

I would like to be able to have a function where I could input a full path and a specific directory and get in return only the right part of the path, removing the left part including the directory specified in the parameter.

In the example given, if I would use:

```
`function('/var/www/sei/modules/module1/', 'sei')`
```

Then I would like to get the result as:

```
`/modules/module1/`
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Explode using / as the delimiter, then work backwards through the array and stop when you get to the name provided in the parameter. Or maybe you could do it using a regular expression. Have you attempted anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ADyson suggested, I wrote this code below:

```
const DIRETORIO_SEI  = 'sei';

private static $caminho;

public static function getCaminhoModulo($append = '') {
    if (self::$caminho != null) {
        return self::$caminho;
    }
    $diretorio = explode('/', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../../'));
    $caminho = '';
    $incluir = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($diretorio); $i++) {
        if ($incluir) {
            $caminho = $caminho . $diretorio[$i] . '/';
        }
        if ($diretorio[$i] == self::DIRETORIO_SEI) {
            $incluir = true;
        }
    }
    self::$caminho = $caminho;
    return $caminho.$append;
}
```